# Are vampires or werewolves immortal in Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter

Does the vampire or werewolf in *Harry Potter* universe possess eternal life?  If so, why don't some ancient vampire or werewolf wizards become the most powerful character, as their experience and knowledge accumulated year by year?

Comment: By _immortal_ do you mean simply not being subject to old age, or in the sense of being literally unable to die, or something in-between?

Comment: I mean  not being subject to old age, as usual fiction suggested.@EvilSnack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Werewolves have no special ability as humans.

Werewolves are not immortal, and do not have any special abilities when there is no full moon.

> “Once a month, at the full moon, the otherwise sane and normal wizard or Muggle afflicted transforms into a murderous beast.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

Newt also explains that the Ministry classification of werewolves only applies to the transformed werewolf, not the human.

> “<sup>16</sup> This classification refers, of course, to the werewolf in its transformed state. When there is no full moon, the werewolf is as harmless as any other human.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

When there is no full moon, werewolves are just like any other human, and equally vulnerable. Indeed, Remus Lupin, a werewolf, dies without any particular fanfare or specific unique measures taken to kill him as a werewolf.

> “As Ginny and Hermione moved closer to the rest of the family, Harry had a clear view of the bodies lying next to Fred: Remus and Tonks, pale and still and peaceful-looking, apparently asleep beneath the dark, enchanted ceiling.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 31 (The Battle of Hogwarts)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, werewolves are not immortal. They do not even seem to be any harder to kill than the average wizard would be.

## Vampires *may* live longer than Muggles.

There is not much canonical information on vampires in the Harry Potter series. The only information about their lifespans are on the Famous Vampires cards, where their lifespan is shown to be unusually long for a Muggle, but on par with wizards.

[image]

However, they are never said to be immortal.

Comment: What/Where are the "Famous Vampires cards" from?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist That's from one of the Harry Potter video games.  I *think* that looks like it's "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban"